# Getting value from a drop down box

Tags: javascript

I have hopefully a simple javascript problem.
I am trying to get the value of a drop down box to help create a dynamic URL. The problem is I am a Javascript novice and where the value should appear in the URL it says "undefined"

This is the script:

```
var imgcon = document.getElementById('imgcon');
var imgconval = imgcon.value;
function getdata(id){window.location = "index.php?id="+id+"&img="+imgconval;}
```

'imgcon' is a drop down box and the number values are appearing correctly when viewing the ource code. Does anyone know how to have var imgconval show the value and not say undefined?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `onchange` event:

```
document.getElementById('imgcon').onchange = function() {
    var imgconval = this.value;
}
```